# scores = score.sentiment(ari_txt, pos, neg, .progress='text') Error in inherits(.data, "split") : object 'ari_txt' not found

Tags: r, analysis

[image: ari_text not found]

scores = score.sentiment(ari_txt, pos, neg, .progress='text')
Error in inherits(.data, "split") : object 'ari_txt' not found

Answer (score 0):

This error message is a result of your first variable `ari_txt` passed to the score.sentiment function not existing in your workspace. Consider creating the variable.